# (hyper) elliptic curve in characteristic two and the Jacobian criterion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic two and let $E$ be a curve given by

$$
y^2=x*(x+1)*(x^2+x+1)*(x^3+x+1)\quad\text{or}\quad y^2=f(x)
$$

Now we have $dy^2/dy=2y=0$ and consider the Jacobian criterion:

$$
J=(f'(x),\:\:\:0\:)
$$
what does this imply for $E$? Where is this curve regular?

I thought that $E$ is regular except at the zeros of $f'$. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One must be careful here: first, one has to distinguish between regular points of the curve and smooth points. $x\in E$ is regular, if the local ring $O_{E,x}$ is regular, that is a discrete valuation ring. $x\in E$ is smooth if $x$ is regular and remains regular after every purely inseparable base change $E\times_k\ell$ of the curve. So regularity and smoothness coincide if $k$ is a perfect field.

The Jacobian criterion (as You apply it) gives the smooth points of $E$, provided $k$ is a perfect field. Under this additional assumption you are right that the regular points $(a,b)\in E$ are precisely the ones satisfying $f^\prime(a)=0$.

Consider the point $(0,0)\in E$: its local ring is $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$, which is a local extension of the local ring $k[x]_{(x)}$. Except $x$ itself all the polynomial factors appearing on the right hand side of the defining equation of $E$ are units in $k[x]_{(x)}$ and therefore in $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. Hence $(x,y)k[x,y]_{(x,y)}=yk[x,y]_{(x,y)}$, because $y^2=ux$ with a unit $u$ of $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. We have shown that the maximal ideal $(x,y)k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$ of the local ring in $(0,0)$ is generated by one element, thus it is a regular local ring and $(0,0)$ is a regular point.

Comment: My advisor scribbled a note next to this example, telling me that the field extension K(E)/K(P^1) is purely inseparable in characteristic two (that I understand), and below he writes: $E$ is singular everywhere.

The only thing I see is '$E$ is ramified everywhere'

Comment: The statement that $E$ is singular everywhere seems wrong -- see the example in the extension of my post.

Comment: Thanks for the post and the example!
A typical field in our case would be $\mathbb Q_p$, which is perfect.